# Horizontal and Vertical recyclerview in NestedScrollView

Tags: android-recyclerview, android-nestedscrollview

I have added 4 RecyclerView inside NestedScrollView. One of them is Hidden, 2 are Horizontal, 1 is Vertical, as per requirement. All of them using Glide to load image but the Vertical one is not clearing/recycling image memory and all glide call makes at Same time.And memory goes to 200+MB because of it.

Here my XML:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
<RecyclerView (Horizontal)
<RecyclerView (Horizontal)
<RecyclerView (Horizontal)
<RecyclerView (Vertical)
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

I have tried  "nestedScrollingEnabled" false already, It worked fine with Horizontal recyclerview but not with vertical one. I am thankful for any Help.

I searched many stackoverflow links, tried some solutions, used OnRecycle method of recyclerview but didnt worked as i needed, Please help!